# Change device name on android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I tried to change the device name on my tablet but for some reason it does not save. After changing I check and it's still the same, don't really know what's happening. I also have included the permissions too, here is my code:

```
BluetoothAdapter myDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
myDevice.setName("new device name");
```

And here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable Developer Options on the tablets, but after doing so, use the following setting.

Settings > Developer Options > Device hostname

This will allow you to change, obviously, the hostname that the tablet uses. You'll want to reboot the tablet to ensure it refreshes properly on the network side. However, not every device may have this option. If you don't see it after enabling Developer Options, use the following method, though it will require root access. You should be able to unroot without having the hostname reset, but don't quote me on that. I'd give it a try with the first tablet to see whether or not it will work.

Install a terminal emulator on the tablet. Enter the following:

Code:

```
> su
> getprop net.hostname
> setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

The 'getprop' command will return the current hostname, so you can double-check it before setting the new one. Again, reboot to refresh network assignments.

http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-1-4-2-4-3-jelly-bean/289961-lots-tablets-how-do-i-rename-them.html#post2872407

Comment: No there isn't that option, So there is no other way around it then? It's because I didn't want to root the device :(

Comment: Which exact tablet are you using?

Comment: samsung galaxy Note 8.0

Comment: Settings>Wireless & Network>WiFi-Direct Settings>Device Name? That's where mine is located.

Comment: No I haven't got that option on mine :(